# Trying to tie the information from three different tables into one with a join query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

So I have three queries I'm trying to join all on the department name field, but I don't know how to do a join on them. Each of my queries below give me some or part of the info I'm looking, but I want the information combined in one table, by department.
the first table is: (total employee count by department)
`

```
    select d.name, count(*)
    from employee e join department d
    on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
    group by d.name;
```

`
which gives me this:

Administration  3
Loans   1
Operations  14

the second is:
`

```
    select d.name, m.emp_id
    from employee e join employee m
    on e.superior_emp_id = m.emp_id
    join department d
    on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
    group by d.name, m.emp_id;
```

`
which gives me this (the manager id number, and which dept they work in)

Operations  3
Loans   4
Operations  6
Operations  10
Operations  13
Operations  4
Operations  16
Administration  1

and my third table:
`

```
    select d.name, b.city
    from employee e join branch b
    on e.assigned_branch_id = b.branch_id
    join department d
    on d.dept_id = e.dept_id
    group by d.name, b.city;
```

`
which gives me this:

Administration  Waltham
Operations  Waltham
Operations  Woburn
Loans   Waltham
Operations  Quincy
Operations  Salem

I want a table that just gives me the sum totals by the dept (admin, loans, operations) for the employees (the first table), the managers (total managers managing employees for each dept) and how many different branch locations each dept is located at. So the query should come back with
Dept| Staff Count | Location Count | Manager Count  with their respective totals by each department.

I'm trying to figure out how to do the join query on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the results you are looking for by using subselects

```
SELECT 
    d.Name AS Dept
   ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee e
    WHERE e.dept_id = d.dept_id ) AS StaffCount
   ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee e 
    JOIN Branch b ON e.assigned_branch_id = b.branch_id
    WHERE e.dept_id = d.dept_id GROUP BY b.city) AS LocationCount
   ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee e
    JOIN Employee m ON e.superior_emp_id = m.emp_id
    WHERE e.dept_id = d.dept_id GROUP BY m.emp_id) AS ManagerCount
 FROM department d
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't get the code to work. I'm also wondering why you are doing doing a where clause with d.dept_id = d.dept_id?

Comment: that was a typo there was a couple of other ones as well.  I created a SQL fiddle for this and I know the syntax is correct.  If you wanted to add some test data I can help troubleshoot errors you are having. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39fa9/1